# When and how does firstChild select #text nodes?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, nodes

Bit new to JS here, so I apologize if this is something obvious. I've read through the relevant [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/firstChild), and I'm a bit perplexed about how and when exactly firstChild selects text nodes.

I have a span and an input like so:

```
     <span class="checkbox">
      <input class="inputs" value="1">
     </span>
```

On page load, if I call:

```
    $(".checkbox").firstChild
```

I'll get back that input html element. Now, if I make an ajax call that replaces the entire span and its input with identical code, and then call:

```
    $(".checkbox").firstChild
```

I get a #text node element back. Why? It may be that a more pertinent question is when are #text nodes inserted into whitespaces?

Please let me know if you need some more context and I appreciate you taking the time to help a beginner out.

Answer (score 0):

Whitespace between nodes creates text nodes, so depending on whether there's any space/newline/tab between the closing `>` of the parent and the opening `<` of the child you may or may not get text nodes.

Use [firstElementChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/firstElementChild) instead. Similar equivalents exist for sibling traversal.

Other options are to adjust your CSS selector to get the first child or use jquery's traversal methods.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me! I'm confused because firstChild works on page load. It only selects a #text node after I've made an ajax call and replaced the code. Is that a known behavior? Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: the point is that your ajax call inserts a text node that wasn't there before.